# Using C#, how do you create a temporary discord voice channel and temporary discord text channel?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have seen ways to do this in Python but not in C#. I can create permanent channels just fine, but I can't find anything online anywhere on how to create a temporary channel.

Comment: Well you could take a look at the documentation/source code of the python libary, but I would bet that it will just deleted it after a certain amount of time.

Comment: You make it.. And when you are done with it, delete it?